# Map Behavior Kinetics option not working?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm creating a JS HERE map (v3.1), but my attempts to change the "kinetics" option have no noticeable effect.  I would like to speed up the default map animation.

```
this.platform = new H.service.Platform({ apiKey: AppKey });

this.layers = this.platform.createDefaultLayers();

this.hereMap = new H.Map(containerElem,
    this.layers.vector.normal.map, {
        center: { lat: center.lat, lng: center.lon },
        zoom: zoom,
    });

this.mapEvents = new H.mapevents.MapEvents(this.hereMap);

this.behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(this.mapEvents,
    { kinetics: { duration: 200, power: 1 }}); // Not working. Why?

this.ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(this.hereMap, this.layers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Map Behavior **Kinetics option is working**.

You are using small values (200 and 1) for kinetic -  `kinetics: { duration: 200, power: 1 }`

Kinetic move behavior is defined only for map panning.

Please set bigger values like:

```
let mapEvents = new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map); 
let behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(mapEvents, {
    kinetics: {duration: 5000, power: 5}
});
```

Worked example you can find on https://jsfiddle.net/8Ljo5xfz/

Comment: Thank you for this reply.  Unfortunately, kinetics: { duration: 5000, power: 5 } does not seem to change the speed of my map animations.  My intent is to animate the map quickly so the user doesn't need to wait for more than a half second.  I had good success doing this with the 3.0 version of the map, and I would like to achieve similar results in the 3.1 version.